# Getting a posterior belief from noisy observations

Tags: heteroscedasticity, unsupervised-learning

Say I have a dataset $X = \{x_i\} \supset \mathbb{R}^n$ for which I assume that $x_i = y_i + \sigma(y_i)$ for some unobserved variables $\{ y_i \}$. That is, I believe that my data is subject to heteroscedastic noise.

From what I see, this rules out methods such as factor analysis.

I am currently searching for methods for the estimation of $p(y_i|x_i)$ on my data. Does this situation have a name? Are there any canonical approaches?

Comment: Why exactly does this rule out factor analysis?

Comment: Because the noise model is not conditioned on the input.